# parsing all options under select in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I have an HTML which has multiple select tags and multiple dropdown options under each select tag
I want to parse all the options under each select and store them

This is how the html looks like

```
<select name="primary_select">
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
</select>
<select name="secondary_select">
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
</select>
```

This is how my code looks like

I am using beautifulsoup and mechanize in python

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.get_data())

```
 subject_options = soup.findAll('select', attrs = {'name': 'primary_select'} ).findAll("option")
print subject_options
```

I am getting the following error

```
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'findAll'
```

Thaks for helping :)

Comment: [`find_all`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) maybe ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`findAll` returns a list in which you can't apply another findAll directly.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''<select name="primary_select">
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
</select>
<select name="secondary_select">
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
</select>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
subject_options = [i.findAll('option') for i in soup.findAll('select', attrs = {'name': 'primary_select'} )]
print subject_options
```

Output:

```
[[<option></option>, <option></option>]]
```

Or

Use css selectors.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
subject_options = soup.select('select[name=primary_select] > option')
print subject_options
```

> I want to parse all the options under each select and store them.

```
subject_options = soup.select('select > option')
print subject_options
```

**output:**

```
[<option></option>, <option></option>, <option></option>, <option></option>]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a `ResultSet` has not attribute `findAll`...

This should work:

```
subject_options = [
    r.findAll('option')
    for r in soup.findAll('select', attrs = {'name': 'primary_select'} )
]
```

But why are you not doing a single request to get the options from the start?

```
subject_options = soup.findAll(
    lambda t: t.name == 'option' and t.parent.attrs.get('name') == 'primary_select'
)
```

Comment: oops, the `.select()` option suggested by @avinash-raj is more readable :^)

Answer (score 0):

A simple modification solved the problem

I just had to add a [0] since it gives a list of all the elements matching the criteria

Thank you for helping :)

```
 subject_options = soup.findAll('select', attrs = {'name': 'primary_select'} )[0].findAll("option")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the compact script

to get the actual value of the selected options I found it works with the .getText() function in case someone also want to extend this.

**Code:**

```
subject_options = soup.select('select[aria-label=Seitenauswahl] > option')

for i in subject_options:
    print(i.getText())

max_pagnation=subject_options[-1].getText()
print("Max=" + max_pagnation)
```

**Output**

```
1
2
3

Max=3
```